# Sending image to a python server in android

Tags: android, python, bitmap

I am trying to send image to the server. I am taking image from imageview, converting it to bitmap then encoding it with in the string format.

```
    profilePic = ( ImageView )findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
```

Now, converting it to string format:
Bitmap bmap = profilePic.getDrawingCache();

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmap, 150, 150, false);

    resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Now sending it to AsyncTask:

```
new ReadFromWeb().execute("update", studentIdString, emailString,
            "http://*****/api/user/update/",
            firstNameString, middleNameString,
            lastNameString, motherNameString
            , fatherNameString,mobileNoString,encodedImage

    );
```

Now, getting it in doInBackground:

```
 data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("profile_pic", "UTF-8") + "="
                        + URLEncoder.encode(params[10],"UTF-8");
```

Sending it via `httpUrlconnection` :

```
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                Log.d(TAG, "SEnd" + data);
                wr.write(data);
```

The image is:

/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
                                                                                AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
                                                                                AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/wAARCACWAJYDASIA
                                                                                AhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQA
                                                                                AAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3
                                                                                ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWm
                                                                                p6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEA
                                                                                AwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSEx
                                                                                BhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElK
                                                                                U1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3
                                                                                uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDlf+Ci
                                                                                ngGez8R/CjxwiMbXWvAOiaNcSvBJGY7zS4VmhR9gWKQXVvqb+UNyyAQS/IWTNfClt8IfEp/Zx/Z7
                                                                                /aI8Z/Fb9l74SeFv2jvFX7QmjfCfw/8AEf4q/Ejw74n1G2/Z5+LviT4U+O9R8SakPgRc/D/w9FJr
                                                                                GiWt7pVhP49n1bUrLVrGKwtbm7ttXtYf2h+Jf/BP/wCPelfsW+JfjL8X/wBoD4i6h4a+FPgyz8Z+
                                                                                FvCPxP8AhN4FtvF2r6hbWZsrTw9J4u8O/H7xqwikuLyKxsfER0OO2ubCezl04ahaPGT+cmt/sifF
                                                                                H9rT9gf/AIIT+EfCvwO+LvxU+HNr+0b/AMFK9A+MOs/DX4dfELxbongTw94p/wCChPiqzt77xvrv
                                                                                gzQdWTwXpV0lpfTf2trFxYQR2Njq16t2sFje3Ef4nUyTA0a/FGa5rlE8cqGDpZnhsLF1p4h2q1JV
                                                                                40qeDxNN1pyjFKnFz5pTjFWje8v37L+LsbPLOEspyjPPqEXjcXlmMxcaOHjDkpYbnwaqyzHA1KdN
                                                                                Rlb2lSm9VNpyVnJ/Klx4C0nXJo7NP2qP2EZ7u8ngtrdB+1N9onlnlkEUEEEZ+HYJkldkjjReWchQ
                                                                                BlmPZfED9jTxJ8FLvwUfiv8AtAfs6+CLj4i+D/hV4+8PLq2h/tvTWzaF8ZYPFt38P7e+1jQv2I9X
                                                                                0a11jV5vBHi+xuNKbUWu9O1Hw9rdnfrHJApb60/4KY/8EdvEPhDwb8GfiD+zV+yr8TLPxB4N+IMO
                                                                                kX3w/wDgj+y18VvGGu+MvCmq6n4cvrfV/FepeDvD+qXlo3w7sdB1YrrniCx1HUfE9zrYsJtVXUob
                                                                                WKX9QfjL4c/aw0rWPgz4k0G6/wCCrPhzwHo/7N37Jfhub4afAv8AYtPj3wFovjTU/wC0fE817Jo+
                                                                                ufFX4dfFK18baXp/hrWdM+Iemar4Kh8H/DrUtT0bw38YrC4g8TyeBPED8PI8LcdZI82pcL4nK6E6
                                                                                lagsLjo5tg8RGVDESpyaVXFL2tOqoKtGpRlOnyyjSnP20K1KPNx1xHxVwxiaGEw3F/8AaE5WlOvQ
                                                                                p5HiKfwOUUnQwC5G5RcWp+91Wnvv8/8A4S/8G+v7c/7Q/wALvAvxr+G/xV/ZCv8AwL8TfC2k+MPB
                                                                                +oar45/aW8PX2o+Gdds1vNH1GfQvEX7JFhrGni9tJIbyCDULK2nMMqyPCokBP5l/tnfsb/Gn/gn1
                                                                                +034f/Ze+Ol38L9Z8SeIvgzp/wAatN1/4UeLvGniDw8mjX/jnX/BkGkXkXi74cfDu+tdRS80C8vJ
                                                                                Ghtbu1Nu9qqXJmadF/q6/Y6/Y7/bQ/aFsft2of8ABQP/AIKLfB3wt8J/F3gvw1rPhD9oT4BeN/gH
                                                                                rfxR0vQrXx9P4ok8ER+E/jd4GtV8H+JE8Zabo1p4xs/D519L3wTo2r31zrF8/wDbVz+Qn/BfHwLN
                                                                                4Y/4Kl/s/wDgi61/WPFdx4T/AOCbPw80S48UeINQ1TVdd8R3WkfHT4g6bPr2tanreq63q1/qeqzw
                                                                                y6he3WpapqN/JczObm+uZS1wfpeIuEsgweQZpiMHgIUa9HDc1Gp9YxrUJ+1Svy1MTUg9NEnFq9lb
                                                                                c8rgrjzi7MuKsowOOzmriMLicRUhXoPC4CKqwjhq81Fyp4WFRXlCLXJOMuZRXMo6P8W9S8NSDRmn
                                                                                ZYmJXenLBj5rMR85Uk7mYli3yjmR2JDMc2XTJYNHsI3CKA8sCALy8ZJyhJG4u5BGGQEjBRQoJb3+
                                                                                /wDDxfQktyhlERVdysACykbCQyF+CcsoK/MShYE1z134dSK0siqqdkrsGUjy0kw/zSBppti87QpZ
                                                                                WZiApHNfhNKhKpCV+W1Oq4yu+Ve7zRautbydnaz6arW39L+3a5WnD3oxU4q+7+J73sm243fVXV3Y
                                                                                +fp9NSLzLMIqDBdsEv8AP87Fni24ic87hu5wA+45Y2NM0K4htuInAuX4ZgyGMksT+7UKwyFGMfKC
                                                                                doIAY16hf6VIqyM6PmVQXUeUwbD7cIoVW+985YZIToHb5q1INKLrawIk0CBhmTcyljIGB8w53DlV
                                                                                Gw+WASGIJbJMY6WHoWjSlLncXHk11c+ZWc+srOyTWlndt2fRheadaX7ynyQjG0uZR0cpJbtLbTVt
                                                                                3a1u2eVX3h65aWKKJkRmkSNUm8yPzCVkbPmH/WFimOFU87csw2s6D4d+KdVuntNOsJJ3uJUijxFL
                                                                                5e4s4Qs5jYjIxuwcNg8DC4+ivDHhPQNzXetXskhtpQ8tiyCKSSELISRKDmAeaqlnkTc6ZIZ35P0P
                                                                                o3xJ8FeHLRbTQPC1nf6ze3OnR6HeXV1ZpbWsh8xJtO1bTZx9m1i3a52SRSJLAzxZguSpYyLzU8BW
                                                                                xPLUnP2NNJNwabnJ8ztZQb0te930ersicTmSo88aFF4qaso+8qUOt3zyWltOjvq03sfFGl/s2fFP
                                                                                V77TrLTtLsL+/uREsdraz3DJBLc3ItLVb+6aBbTTlnn2wRz3dwlmk8qJPKu8McvW/hN8V/BfiTWP
                                                                                A3iXwF4m0fxNo2rXOgXuiyWdzLex6taXstneWSRQ2xWdhcJ5QaMurK8b26yIQ9fZ0nxi8WeBr7x3
                                                                                cTeINS8GTTW82mXU+m65d6LpI8OXNzNc3ehXsiXNvHfaQouP9AgvLq4tYYJmjiBj2MfK9G+KWif2
                                                                                zbazpuoXVxLOWuLTVluLre4Aje0vLdi8EsyuI45ra5+Uy5+0QSmMI7c+cU8FTw14wx8ZRlBVK6jG
                                                                                pSS52lGFP2Mp88ttJX967binfXJsXmUq1SdSpl0KdSMIQpSnU9spc825VKiqezUEtrKab5tYu7Pm
                                                                                fTNMuoZ9kuhalDJbmMzGazk/dvLMzEFREreYAmZFYOqqEXerbUPYy+H4mMIn0u6TzkyHu7Se337d
                                                                                6mUfaLf5o3bIzhhvGGyVzX1rpHjHwTqP2ybxP4tNpqDzxu9uNB169llBK42S6Zpt/wCYxLyyPLLK
                                                                                ZvlCAMzBW9Bj+J/wYLQWl541EIiCW8l3f+GvG1zLGigqMGXw5Kmx2ySkbny+VKoQ5r8uzzM6lGT+
                                                                                qYDNcTGKjCMv7PquU2rty5Yq9ktbpJWtdNq5+oZRg8JWajisflNNzhzSl/aNKKjLmcbS9pKCSTu9
                                                                                XdJq+rkj4o0nwxGEuMRxGOJWRDsBI3wjesWIFUfIVRcYB2

But the server is not uploading it. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Please show the server code for that endpoint. Its likely that is a server issue and not an Android one.

Comment: `encoding it with in the string format.` String format??? I see that you base64 encode a jpeg image. You are not encoding a Bitmap. A jpeg image is made from the bitmap first. Please name all at start.

Comment: Do not url encode the base64 string when you post it to the server. You have not told how the server expects all data.

Comment: `But the server is not uploading it`. Well your Android app is sending/uploading it. The python server should receive it and probably save it somewhere. Which errors at server side? Doesnt the server echo back info about a good post? You should read that info in your Android app otherwise your app is blind.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, For Server Side with Flask api to get image(base64) and save it to in server.

```
@app.route('/api/create_category',methods=['POST'])
def image():
user_id = request.json["user_id"]
cat_name = request.json["category_name"] 
desc = request.json["description"]
img = request.json["image"]
filename = (user_id+date+".png")
img_url = "/".join([target,filename])
with open(img_url, "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(base64.b64decode(img))
print(img_url,file=sys.stderr)
db.category.insert({"user_id":user_id,"category_name":cat_name,"desription":desc,"img_url":img_url})
return jsonify({"result":{"message":"success"}})
```

And form Android need to upload image in base64 by using Volley

```
    HashMap<String,String> params =  new HashMap<>();
            params.put("user_id",user_id);
            params.put("category_name",category_name);
            params.put("description",description);
            params.put("image", imagetoString(bitmap));
            JSONObject parameter =  new JSONObject(params);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObject = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, parameter, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d("response", response.toString());
            try {
                String result = response.getJSONObject("result").get("message").toString();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });


RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    queue.add(jsonObject);
```